# How to deal: external Jenkins port does not work

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, jenkins

I have jenkins service working fine on internal and local levels (I can just open localhost:8080 or 192.168.x.x:8080 in the browser and it gives me Jenkins "sign in" page)

But I have troubles using external IP. What I did (ubuntu machine):

- checked port using `netstat -tuln | grep 8080` (it's LISTEN) - **OK**
- allowed firewall `sudo ufw allow 8080` - **OK**
- forwarded port through my router (inside my router settings specified local IP, internal port and external port) - **OK**
  [image]
- pinged external IP x.x.x.x from different machine - **OK**
- connecting from different machine to x.x.x.x:8080 - **FAIL**

```
PS C:\Users\sagec> (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.31.190 -Port 8080).TcpTestSucceeded                        
True    

PS C:\Users\sagec> (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName x.x.x.x -Port 8080).TcpTestSucceeded
WARNING: TCP connect to (x.x.x.x: 8080) failed
False

PS C:\Users\sagec>
```